# how to get the json key value pair in specific format and fill key/value in select box

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON array like below:

```
var regions = {
    "af": "Africa",
    "as": "Asia",
    "au": "Australia",
    "at": "Austria",
    "be": "Belgium",
    "uk": "Engalnd",
    "fr": "France",
    "us": "USA"
}
```

i am using simple code like below:

```
<option value="">Please Select Country</option>
    {if regions!=undefined}
        {for r in regions}
            <option value="${r}" >${r}</option>
        {/for}
    {/if}
```

I wanted to extract key and value and also want to pass to option value in above code.
How can i do this in above code

Comment: Are you using some sort of templating engine. That doesn't look like JS code.

Comment: yes i m using some template

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript we can do by

```
for (r in regions){
     html += "<option value="+r+">"+regions[r]+"</option>";
}
```

To get id and value in jst template

```
{for r in regions}
<option value="${r_index}" >${r}</option>
{/for}
```

Comment: That's not valid JavaScript, -1.

Comment: i just mentioned above was how to retrieve the key and its value and i don't about your template.. may be i'll change with the help of anton

Comment: I am getting regions in ${r} i want to find out key means {"af":"africa"} so i want to find af

Comment: it is something like smarty but i don't know actually

Comment: i think you were using jst template just try the above mentioned code